# Getting form values with MvcPager

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0

When I select any page of my `PagedList<T>` the `[HttpGet]`method is activated. Because of this, Im not able to use `Request.Form.GetValues()`.

I just saw the `Request`variable into the immediate window and realized that I dont see any value that I want from the IDs that I have ( the request dont bring me any value of any ID of the screen, since Im not using the post method).

I got a grid (table) and one field of each record is a checkbox, after the pagination, I need know wich checkbox is enabled to keep it checked ( I already made the code to keep it checked, I just need to know how Im going to see if those checkboxes are checked.

I already know their ID too.

Im using the following control to generate those checkboxes:

```
//foreachloop 
<%: Html.CheckBox(item.ID.ToString(), item.isChecked)%>
```

For my pagination, Im using the following:

Aspx: 
    <%: Html.Pager(Model.ListaGridPaginada)%>

This pager is a overload that calls the following:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Pager(this HtmlHelper helper, int totalPageCount, int pageIndex, string actionName, string controllerName, 
        PagerOptions pagerOptions, string routeName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        var builder = new PagerBuilder
            (
                helper,
                actionName,
                controllerName,
                totalPageCount,
                pageIndex,
                pagerOptions,
                routeName,
                routeValues,
                htmlAttributes
            );
        return builder.RenderPager();
    }
```

I call the method wich constructs this variable with the following parameters:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Pager<T>(this HtmlHelper helper, PagedList<T> pagedList)
    {
        if (pagedList == null)
            return Pager(helper,null, null);
        return Pager(helper, pagedList.TotalPageCount, pagedList.CurrentPageIndex, null, null, null,null, null,null);
    }
```

This pagerHelper is from [Webdiyer](http://en.webdiyer.com)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you wrap it in a form and you set the method to GET, then it should pass in all of your form values into the query string. Something like this:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Controller", "Action", FormMethod.Get))
{
    // grid in here
    //foreachloop 
    <%: Html.CheckBox(item.ID.ToString(), item.isChecked)%>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

When you click the submit button, your query string will look something like this:

```
Action?ID1=false&ID2=true&ID2=false
```

Which, you'll look at the query string to determine if the checkbox ID contains true. See how ID1=false, but ID2 is true and false? That means ID1 was unchecked, but ID2 was checked.

```
Request.QueryString["ID2"].Contains("True")
```

If that doesn't work for you, you could keep track of which checkboxes are checked with javascript by putting their checked state in a hidden value and passing that around.

Does that help any?

Comment: Thanks for response, Hawkke. The problem is that I need the POST method. Setting the method to GET would loose all my action set up into the post function.

Comment: In that case, I would use the hidden field. When a box is checked, add that box's ID to the hidden field; when it is unchecked, remove the ID. The hidden field would be posted as a string parameter to your controller. You could use javascript / jquery to parse the hidden field and check the boxes with the correct IDs in the page ready event.