# Keeping CheckBoxes checked through pagination

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a grid with the following object:

```
public PagedList<GridList> PagedList { get; set; }


public class GridList
{
    public Employee EmployeeItem { get; set; }
    public bool isChecked { get; set; }
}
```

My aspx implemented the table inside a loop and then I put a checkbox for each Employee:

```
 <%foreach (var item in Model.PagedList )
   {%>
      <tr>
         <td align="center">
            <%: Html.CheckBox(item.EmployeeItem.ID.ToString(), item.isChecked)%>
        </td>
     </tr>
<% }%>
```

I need to keep all the checkboxes selected when the user change the page. So, if he selects 2 or 3 options of a page an then change the page number, when he come back to this page, the same checks should be marked.

I tried many solutions but I wont comment them here just to expect a better one. All the orders I tryed I had problems that I cannot solve.

When the user click to got to another page, the code goes to the `[HttpGet]` method.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @AdamRackis Yes, I'm using jQuery..

Answer (score 0):

You will have to somehow send the checked values to the server when performing pagination or you will loose them. You have a couple of possibilities:

1. Put the checkboxes inside an HTML form alongside with the pager and make the pager links submit buttons of this form.
2. Use AJAX to perform the pagination and refresh only the grid portion of the DOM and do not *touch* at the checkboxes. This way they will preserve their values.
3. Subscribe to the `onclick` event of the pager links and inside cancel the default action (`evt.preventDefault()`), harvest the values of the checkboxes and append them to the query string of the url that will perform the pagination. Then redirect to this new url.

Comment: Wich one is the most commonly used, Darin ? The first option isn't already used since `Html.CheckBox`is a HTML field ? Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Dan-SP, this will depend on your exact scenario, how are you generating and handling pagination links, ... That's why I presented the 3 options. They are all commonly used.

Comment: I see. Yesterday, I created [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465606/getting-form-values-with-mvcpager) trying to explain what Im exactly doing. Im using the MVCPager to perform my pagination

Comment: @Dan-SP, in this question you haven't shown the code how you are generating page links. Ideally you should show your view, models and controllers.

Comment: Darin,  just updated with the information you asked ( I think). Anyway, that pager helper got a huge variery of overloads, I just show the one Im using.